# how to get particular value from json array?

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I have the json array name like as newarr.How to get the all id's from the json array and how to add with in the arr value?

```
 var arr=new Array();
 var newarr=new Array([
        {
            "id": 16820,
            "value": "abcd",
            "info": "Centre"
        },
        {
            "id": 18920,
            "value": "abcd-16820",
            "info": "Centre"
        },
        {
            "id": 1744,
            "value": "abcd-16820",
            "info": "Centre"
        },
        {
            "id": 16822,
            "value": "AaronsburgPA-16820",
            "info": "Centre"
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with jQuery and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuGw2/) for it.

```
$.each(newarr[0], function(k, v) {
    arr.push(v.id);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: jquery... lame ;) i still don't see why one wouldn't use `map` for that :-/

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
for (var o in newarr){
    arr.push(newarr[o].id);
}
```

also, you don't need to use both square brackets and `new Array` when building an array object, one of the other will do:

```
var myarray = new Array(1,2,3);
```

or

```
var myarray = [1,2,3];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

```
for(prop in newArr) {
    arr.push(newArr[prop].id);
}
```

Allow me to suggest that instead of coming directly to Stack Overflow for help, you Google around a bit next time. :) Also, that is not a JSON array: it's a Javascript array. And it's better to initialize an array with `[]` notation (`var arr = []`).

Answer (score 0):

Both given answers won't work, because you are creating a nested array (`newarr=new Array([...])`).

The algorithm is: loop through the Array containing objects, and `push` the value of  every object.id to `arr`.

In you case:

```
for (var i=0;i<newarr[0].length;i+=1){
  if (newarr[0][i].id) {
    arr.push(newarr[0][i].id);
}
```

furthermore: this is not a 'JSON Array'. [There are no such things as JSON Objects/Arrays](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` method on array:

```
arr = newarr.map(function(obj) { return obj.id })
```

And a link to the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

If you don't have an id in every object, you might want to `filter` null:

```
arr = newarr.map(function(obj) {  
  return obj.id  
}).filter(function(id){  
  return id !== undefined  
})
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

and if you really have a nested array, do this first:

```
newarr = newarr[0]
```

and here is a link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3SjV/)